# count elements in one column based on another column-Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to know which element in one column has the same number of occurence based on 3 groups in a different column.

Here is how the df looks like :
[image]
Here is the exact question: 
How many sports distributed exactly the same number of Gold, Silver and Bronze medals?

Comment: Can you copy paste sample data instead of image so it is easy for others to attempt answering ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: sure. done thank you.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: Please clarify if you'd like to know (1) each sport that, within the sport, gave the same number of gold, silver, and bronze, or (2) the size of groups of sports that gave out common counts of gold, silver, and bronze (eg swimming and rowing both gave 1 gold, 2 silver, and 5 bronze).

Comment: I need to know each sport that within that sport, there were same number of Gold, Silver and Bronze medals were distributed.

Answer (score 0):

The core of what you need to do is to pivot your table and aggregate with count.

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[['Aquatics', 'Swimming', 'Gold'],
          ['Aquatics', 'Swimming', 'Silver'],
          ['Aquatics', 'Swimming', 'Silver'],
          ['Aquatics', 'Rowing', 'Gold'],
          ['Aquatics', 'Rowing', 'Bronze']],
     columns=['Sport', 'Discipline', 'Medal']
)

>>> df[['Discipline', 'Medal']]\
        .pivot_table(index='Discipline', columns='Medal', aggfunc=len)\
        .reset_index()\
        .fillna(value=0)

      Discipline  Bronze  Gold  Silver
0         Rowing     1.0   1.0     0.0
1       Swimming     0.0   1.0     2.0
```

From here, you could do a group by or something to group up sports that had the same medal counts.  Or if you're trying to track down sports that distributed the same number of each medal within the sport, apply a filter with

```
df[(df['Gold'] == df['Silver']) & (df['Silver'] == df['Bronze'])]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. your suggestion solved my issue

Comment: You can mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem to indicate to future viewers that it's been resolved.